# How to cross select some data

Tags: php, mysql

I am sorry if this has also been answerd in some previous issue, but I need some help.

I have a table, something like:

```
x       y  

1       a 

1       c

2       e 

2       g
```

So what I actually need is to display all the data in this table using this format:
(not sure if I understand it but.. )

if `x=1`  display on the first row of a table a and on the second display b

Such as:

```
Row 1   Row 2   Row 3

1       a       c

2       e       g
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don`t actually want the full script if you think it's too much of a trouble, but at least point me to witch function I should use.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many columns there are going to be in this "report"? In your example they are `Row1, Row2, Row3`, but there could be more of them? Second question: have you considered an aggregate function instead?

Comment: This isn't a good question. you need to make an effort to solve your own problem and THEN ask for help. This is like do it for me.

Comment: allen, I tried and all I managed to do is to echo all the datas like they are in the first table. I didn't ask you to do it for me, jsut at least point me to which function/operation I should focus on. A hint or something. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @AlexVieriu Please answer the second question: have you considered an aggregate function instead, like `GROUP_CONCAT()`? Is there a reason why you need 3 columns and can't use an aggregate function?

Comment: I didn`t know what that meant. I'm new to this. I will research on the aggregate functions and GROUP_CONCAT especially and see where it goes.

Comment: Alex, please take a look at the MySQL [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) and [`MIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) functions. The examples that accompany these are pretty much your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Suppose your table name is **test**

```
$sql = 'SELECT x, y FROM `test`;';
$run = mysql_query( $sql );


$data = array();
if( $run && mysql_num_rows( $run ) ) {
   while( ( $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc( $run ) ) !== false ) {
       $data[ $fetch[ 'x' ] ][] = $fetch[ 'y' ];
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Row 1</th>
         <th>Row 2</th>
         <th>Row 3</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      foreach( $data as $key => $row ) {
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $key;?></td>
          <?php
          foreach( $row as $value ) {
          ?>
          <td><?php echo $value;?></td>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works thanks. That's actually just what I needed. But I didn't quite understood it.

Comment: Now, 1 maps to (a,a,c,c) and 2 maps to (e,e,g,g). So, the code will still work, but will have 5 columns instead of original 3. This is a base code, you can modify it as your requirements change.

Comment: Yes but if I'd wanted to hide those 2 extra columns? and still keep only those original 3?

Comment: If you want to show only 3, **add** `$row=array_slice($row,0,2);` **after** `foreach( $data as $key => $row ) {`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. And another question if it's not too much of a trouble. Not sure if you'll understand me but there it goes:

How can I "use" the outputed variables? For instance:

It did echo on the first row 'a' and I would like to use ONLY that one variable. How do I "select" it?